# How to detect if UITextField is an @me address?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am building a mail client and want to know how I can detect if the text field has @me in it. Preferably using an if statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the text property of the text field contains "@me.com" as a substring.

```
if ([textField.text rangeOfString:@"@me.com"].location != NSNotFound) {

    //@me.com email

} else {

    //not an @me.com email

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *text = someTextField.text;
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"@me"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // string has @me in it
}
```

I prefer to split up the code a bit. This makes it easier to read and debug. It also makes it easier if you need to use the values further along in the code.